# Lockfile creation failed

Tags: linux, logging, locking

I got a plain-text logfile (not lock file) in /var/log what I cannot open with:

```
lockfile creation failed: exceeded maximum number of lock attempts
```

I wonder what causes this and how can I unlock it without rebooting the server or other drastic measures.

```
lsof +D /var/log/backups/
```

Checking it with lsof nothing else is accessing this directory and the rsync process which output was redirected to this log file is terminated already.

I can open all other log files in this directory.

The stats on this file are:

```
 File: `backup-2015-02-08.log'
  Size: 67          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 841h/2113d  Inode: 542598      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-02-09 08:00:05.496366834 +0100
Modify: 2015-02-08 20:30:02.486312676 +0100
Change: 2015-02-08 20:30:02.486312676 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Given that the error message is clear that it's a lockfile that can't be created, why are you so sure it's really a logfile?  Show us more evidence.

Comment: How are you trying to open it ? Do you have sufficient space/inodes to create a lock file ...